# Context: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to keep a live state of either the user is signed-in or not, so I can either show him or not, specific elements in the components. Using this code it's supposed to `console.log(0)` and then `console.log(1)`, but it actually throws an error `Cannot read properties of undefined`.

**./addons/Signed.js:**

```js
import { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const SignedContext = createContext();

export default function SignedProvider(props) {
  const [SignedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(0);

  return (
    <SignedContext.Provider value={{ SignedIn, setSignedIn }}>
      {props.children}
    </SignedContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**./screens/Profile.js:**

```js
import { useContext } from "react";

import SignedContext from "../addons/Signed";

...

const ProfileScreen = () => {
  const { SignedIn, setSignedIn } = useContext(SignedContext);

  console.log(SignedIn);

  setSignedIn(1);

  console.log(SignedIn);

  ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `named export` for `SignedContext` but using a `default import` in `Profile`. Thus, you must use curly braces for your import. The following should change your issue.

```js
import { SignedContext } from ".../addons/Signed"
```

**Edit:** If `ProfileScreen` is not a child of `SignedContext.Provider`, then this will not work. The general workflow is documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Hence, if `ProfileScreen` is not a child of the Provider, the context won't be available to it.

The ususal way to do this, is to define the context provider as a top level element in your app, if you want the context to be available at a global level in your application.

```js
function App = () => {
   const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(0)

   const contextValue = React.useMemo(() => ({signedIn, setSignedIn}), [singedIn])

    // your application structure must be wrapped inside here.
   // as an example I have only used ProfileScreen. 
   // Usually this is your root stack.
   return (
       <SignedContext.Provider value ={contextValue}>
          <ProfileScreen />
       </SignedContext.Provider>
   )
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error... Am I supposed to add the provider in `App.js` somehow?

Comment: Is ProfileScreen in `props.children` of SignedProvider?

Comment: No, the code I've pasted is all I've done with `Context`... How can I do that? :-) EDIT: I just imported `SignedProvider` in `App.js` and wrapped everything in `<SignedProvider></SignedProvider>` and now I get error `Cannot update a component (`SignedProvider`) while rendering a different component (`ProfileScreen`).` when I try to update the state from `ProfileScreen`.

Comment: See me edited answer please.

Comment: I didn't realise I have to wrap everything in `App.js` with the provider... Thank you so much, it's working now!

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad it worked out.